# Why does set attribute occur in reverse here?

Tags: java, xml, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Control order of XML attributes in outputed file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087602/control-order-of-xml-attributes-in-outputed-file-in-java)

I have this code:

```
 Element node = testDoc.createElement("image_file");
 node.setAttribute("id", count);
 node.setAttribute("file_name", fileNameCombinedWithPNG);
```

My XML has `filename` before the `id`, no matter what I do, even when I switch the orders of the set attributes, the output of the XML looks the same, i.e the it's:

```
image_file filename="xyz" id="1" as but I want is image_file id="1" filename="adfx"
```

Comment: XML attributes don't have to be in order. Any tool that depends on the order is buggy.

Comment: I want them in order, how can I make it in order sir

Comment: There are questions here dealing with this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8087602/422353  http://stackoverflow.com/q/7526062/422353

Comment: Do you really need it to be in order. Attributes can be in any order for xml, so toolkits have their own discretion when rendering xml documents. It appears in the toolkit you are using it is using an ordered list to store the attributes. You may fix it for this list but then the toolkit might swap to a hash set. In other words in trying to fix the order you are creating a lot of pain for yourself.

Comment: @madth3 Make that comment of yours an answer, because it's the correct answer.

Comment: Flagged as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8087602/422353

Comment: I'm still a student guys, I appreciate your help. Now I get it. Long live StackOverflow. :)